# What are the advantages of parallel pushrod configuration?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, automotive-engineering

A topic that came up in a recent discussion was pushrod engines (specifically V2 configuration in a motorcycle) with four cams. After some googling, I was able to find an example in the Harley-Davidson Evolution engine (used in the Sportster models).

Four distinct camshafts add a lot of complexity, because they need to be driven by separate gears. From what I've been able to find, the main reason to do that is in the different tappet construction, which requires the tappet to be directly "over" the camshaft:

> Now it appears Harley may have decided to adopt roller-tipped sliding square or cylindrical tappets of the kind being used in large numbers by makers of radial aircraft engines—notably the Wright-Lawrance J-series engines, one of which would in 1927 power Charles Lindbergh’s solo flight across the Atlantic. Because these had to be located directly above the cam lobe, the simplest way to have the distinctive parallel pushrods that the A, B, and C-model Harley singles employ was to have a separate camshaft under each.
>
> [How the Harley-Davidson Sportster Came to Have Four Cams](https://www.cycleworld.com/how-the-harley-davidson-sportster-motorcycle-came-to-have-four-cams/)

I don't really understand this explanation. Why does putting the tappet at an angle like dual- or single-cam engine do prevent using the aircraft engine technology? As far as I can imagine, those are also directly "over" the camshaft (meaning radially), they just reside at an angle that enables driving two rocker arms in the head.

In fact, I was able to find numerous examples of HD engines with roller-tipped tappets that used only one camshaft. So if that's technically possible, what specifically was gained by the parallel tappet layout?

Comment: A numerous (and I believe incorrect) explanations include that it was ["stylish"](https://books.google.pl/books?id=Xe4prmt78TcC&pg=PA32&lpg=PA32&dq=parallel+pushrods+harley&source=bl&ots=IaPfVNOCKk&sig=ACfU3U1oqLxNOt7EGEeoFrw0nk6bEChHdQ&hl=pl&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiX_ISP7qLkAhWplIsKHRatDOAQ6AEwFXoECAYQAQ#v=onepage&q=parallel%20pushrods%20harley&f=false), or that it allows ["for VERY powerful cams"](https://www.lowbrowcustoms.com/blog/a-brief-history-of-the-harley-davidson-evolution-engine/#sthash.S0l9985a.dpbs) (which just sounds gibberish).

Comment: There's also [another article by Kevin on the same subject](https://www.cycleworld.com/more-on-how-harley-davidson-sportster-motorcycle-came-to-have-four-cams/), which really leaves the matter in a confused state: _Unless someone out there knows for sure, that may be as far as we can get with our quest for the origins of the Harley Sportster’s four separate camshafts._ Bummer.

Comment: What do you mean: "*Why does putting the tappet at an angle like dual- or single-cam engine do prevent usingthe roller tips?*"

Comment: @SolarMike I was referring to the quote above. I mean, it obviously doesn't, that's the point I'm not getting. I've edited to clarify.